# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a big java with a Gradle project about 500MB which I can smoothly run it on Win7 JDK 11.0.7 and eclipse 4.15.0. The problem is that when I try to deploy it on mac with the exact configuration, it raised the following exception, the hurdle is that I'm unable to understand the reason.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.workcraft.plugins.circuit.CircuitModule
at org.workcraft.LegacyPluginInfo.create(LegacyPluginInfo.java:75)
at org.workcraft.PluginManager$PluginInstanceHolder.newInstance(PluginManager.java:62)
at org.workcraft.PluginManager.initModules(PluginManager.java:137)
at org.workcraft.PluginManager.loadManifest(PluginManager.java:131)
at org.workcraft.PluginManager.loadManifest(PluginManager.java:77)
at org.workcraft.Framework.initPlugins(Framework.java:842)
at org.workcraft.Console.main(Console.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.workcraft.plugins.circuit.CircuitModule
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.workcraft.LegacyPluginInfo.loadClass(LegacyPluginInfo.java:110)
    at org.workcraft.LegacyPluginInfo.create(LegacyPluginInfo.java:71)
    ... 6 more
```

Could you please explain what does this mean, and is there any suggestions.

Comment: It means there is a class *org.workcraft.plugins.circuit.CircuitModule* that you compiled  and tested with on Windows, but that is missing on the Mac. This class may be part of a larger collection of classes in a .jar file. If you reference the JavaDocs for ClassNotFoundException, it will tell you something similar

Comment: A very helpful comment. But please one more question, please. Do you mean that I have to copy CircuitModule.class manually to Mac?

Comment: To get CircuitModule on the classpath, you either need to have your classpath include the root directory above org/workcraft/plugins/circuit/ (the package) or have the classpath include the jar where CircuitModule is in org/workcraft/plugins/circuit (a jar file is essentially a zip file with a few added bells and whistles). The latter is generally easier in terms of deployment.

Comment: Thank you. You made my day!